# What's the quickest way to start playing a movie after attaching power?

Tags: debian, video, boot

I want my Raspberry Pi to start looping a predefined `.mp4` movie (`/home/oliver/awesome.mp4`) as soon as possible after attaching power to the device.

This has to happen without any user interaction and I would prefer it if no OSD is distracting the playback. I want to use this next to a [POS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POS_terminal) for entertainment purposes.

Comment: Would you be trying to set it up as a Splash page? also how long?

Comment: The best way to do this varies depending on the distro. Which are you using?

Comment: @Jivings: I assume to be using Debian.

Comment: "I want to use this next to a POS for entertainment purposes." Sorry, I couldn't help but laugh! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly make sure you boot straight into X.
For details on this, please see this question:
[Auto-start X-windows / gdm on the standard Debian build](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/586/auto-start-x-windows-gdm-on-the-standard-debian-build)

Then edit your `~/.xinitrc` file. It needs to contain the command that starts your media player:

```
vim ~/.xinitrc
omxplayer -p -o hdmi /home/oliver/awesome.mp4
```

This will make the video begin as soon as X does.

Comment: If you're going down this route for the answer, could you provide details on how to make your Pi go straight into X?

Comment: @recantha I think that would be out of the scope of this question. But you should be able to find it somewhere on this site.

Comment: _I_ know how to do it, it would just be a more complete answer if you provided the details.

Comment: @recantha See [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/587/40)

Comment: omxplayer works also from the command line, so it's not necessary to start X at all. How about starting omxplayer from /etc/rc.local ?

Comment: @Frepa Hm. Yes you're right. I forgot omxplayer just hijacks the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by Frepa, there is a faster way.

Here a way to auto login and start a script: http://www.akeric.com/blog/?p=1976

Sust make the script to start omxplayer with the video you want.