# Auto-start X-windows / gdm on the standard Debian build

Tags: debian, boot, gdm, xorg

I've built a bootable SD from the official Debian release.

Is there an easy way to get GDM to auto-start when the machine boots (like a typical Linux desktop)?

For bonus points, is there a way to get it to auto-login?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes indeed.

### Starting GDM At Boot

You need to edit `/etc/inittab` so that `init` knows that it should boot directly into runlevel 5 (default for X11) when it starts.

> **Beginners note**: Lines that begin with a `#` represent comments. They will be ignored completely when the file is used.

This section controls the default runlevel:

```
## Only one of the following two lines can be uncommented!
# Boot to console
# id:3:initdefault: # this line should be commented
# Boot to X11
id:5:initdefault:  # this line should be uncommented
```

You then need to tell it what command to run when it starts runlevel 5. This section controls that:

```
# Example lines for starting a login manager
#x:5:respawn:/usr/bin/xdm -nodaemon
x:5:respawn:/usr/sbin/gdm -nodaemon        # this line should be uncommented
#x:5:respawn:/usr/bin/kdm -nodaemon
#x:5:respawn:/usr/bin/slim >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Now when you reboot you should boot directly into GDM.

### Auto Login

After logging in run the command:

```
sudo gdmsetup
```

Select the `Security Tab`, click the `Enable Automatic Login`, select your username from the menu and close.

After the next reboot you should be automatically logged in.

Comment: I'm now using he Wheezy Debian build for Rpi - is there a specific package which contains gdmsetup.

Comment: I thought it was part of the gdm package. You should be able to edit the confit file manually instead though.