# When set to boot in to X-server, RasPi is booting without password

Tags: boot, raspbian, gui, gdm

Regardless of whether I boot to a GUI or to the console, I always want a password enabled on all of my machines.

I've looked at as many tutorials as I can find regarding this, and although there are apparently a myriad of ways to make debian boot to x and login automatically, I'm not using any of them that I can see. When I use the raspi-config script to set to boot GUI on startup, it bypasses my user password entry. As I have more than one user, this does not work.

So this question is, "How do I securely boot into x-server, maintaining a password before entering the GUI on Raspbian?"

**EDIT:**

The code on the line beginning 'sed' appears to set an auto-login function, if I don't misunderstand?

```bash
do_boot_behaviour() {
  whiptail --yesno "Should we boot straight to desktop?" 20 60 2
  RET=$?
  if [ $RET -eq 0 ]; then # yes
    update-rc.d lightdm enable 2
    sed /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf -i -e "s/^#autologin-user=.*/autologin-user=pi/"
    ASK_TO_REBOOT=1
  elif [ $RET -eq 1 ]; then # no
    update-rc.d lightdm disable 2
    ASK_TO_REBOOT=1
  else # user hit escape
    return 1
  fi
}
```

Comment: Do you have GDM installed then?

Comment: How do I figure out what packages I would need? And it appears that the raspi-config script is doing this, unless I misunderstand? See edited question for code snippet.

Comment: Please check the answer. It will help site stats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, find the line that says

```
autologin-user=pi
```

and comment it out; it should look like

```
#autologin-user=pi
```

You will have to do this as `root`.

Comment: I've done this over SSH, but I will have to wait until I get home from work to check its efficacy. I'll let you know. Did you get that location from the code above, or did you know this some other way?

Comment: It's the 'sed' line. Basically saying to replace the commented auto-login line in that file with an uncommented one and a specified user. Right?

Comment: @zenbike Right, I deduced the solution from the `sed` script.

Comment: So, while it does cause the pi to require a login, it does not use GDM, rather, the login is required in the console, and the GUI no longer starts until I manually input startx.

Comment: @zenbike see this question http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/586/auto-start-x-windows-gdm-on-the-standard-debian-build for info on how to make it start xwindows on startup.

Comment: Installing Slim rather than LightDM, allowed me to use xwindows on start up, while still requiring a user login before accessing the machine.  Still can't get LightDM to do that.

Comment: @zenbike I keep meaning to try `lightdm`, so I'll try it when I get back from Italy and see if I can make it bow to my commands.