# Raspbian login to GUI requiring password?

Tags: raspbian

Is there a way that I can set my Pi to log in to the X server GUI but still require my username and password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/boot-to-login-screen-raspberry

Comment: @dastaan: incorrect. That link just demonstrates how to set the rPi to boot straight to GUI. The OP wants to set a login before the GUI starts (or a GUI login screen). This post is closer: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/when-set-to-boot-in-to-x-server-raspi-is-booting-without-password?rq=1

Comment: @PhilB. You're right. My bad. The one you suggested actually does what he wants i.e., GUI login screen. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Anyways, my quick research showed no RaspberryPi.SE post that addressed this specific question, so I don't think closure is needed. I found an Instructable that answers it - see my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

[This Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-Raspberry-Pi-a-Multi-User-Desktop/) (on Instructable.com) gives you the right clues on how to set up a Login screen inside the GUI:

> Open terminal emulator
>
> `cd /etc/lightdm`
>
> `nano lightdm.conf`
>
> Disable auto login:
>
> `#auto-login-user=pi`
>
> Show list of user(s) in login screen
>
> `greet-hide-users=false`
>
> Save the file
>
> Reboot
>
> `sudo reboot`
>
> Raspberry Pi will display a login screen

Comment: My raspbian is not booting after I applied this change. The boot stops at a black screen when it should open the greet screen and prompt for password